# how to Sign in to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I try to sign in to Google Cloud Platform using Google Cloud SDK Shell.

I used the command `gcloud auth login` but it says `'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable programme or batch file`.

Comment: Your SDK is not installed properly; meaning it is not in your path. What platform are you on?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie I'm on windows

Comment: Sorry, I don't know then. The installer on windows should automatically add that path for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just navigate to the directory that your google app engine is installed and find the executable and try adding it to your path.  My directory for the google app engine is:

C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin

You could try re-installing the google app engine sdk which might add it to your path or change the variable yourself through adjusting your Path environment variable in system properties.

Comment: Adding the variable to path does not fix the problem; for me it was already in path. I have the problem even when I navigate to the `C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin` directory and run `gcloud.cmd`.

Comment: I would try downloading the zip file containing all the sdk components, unzipping it in some directory and adding that to your path.  I had to do that recently with the new versions of the sdk that were pushed.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install the sdk using this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/).

Issue the command `gcloud init.`